Ubuntu fails to start the GUI after update
I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on Lenovo Legion. I recently upgraded a lot of packages (precisely, I used sudo apt update followed by sudo apt upgrade. Since then, I have been unable to use GUI. The startup screen shows [FAILED] Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon. (I can, however, log in using one of the ttys.)
I have no idea how to fix this, or find the issue. And I cannot copy and paste logs here from my system without GUI access.
Any help is much appreciated.
I logged in through one of the ttys, and checked the /var/log/syslog. It says the same thing: Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
I don't know what this means, and how this broke my GUI startup.
